# Mysql fetch user data returning nil value

Tags: php, mysql

I recently received -3 ratings for my recent question though the solution wasn't provided. My apologies if I posted something which I shouldn't have.

Alright so it is related to that ques only I have this code:

```
$data = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
$data = mysql_query("SELECT `location` FROM `upload` WHERE `name` = '".$result['name']."'")
or die(mysql_error());  
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
$display_url = $info['createlink'];
```

So when I echo $display_url it returns nil value and in db I checked the createlink field  and the value stored there is a link.
And when I use

```
$display_url = $info['location'];
```

It returns perfect value.

~~The field at createlink contains 'http://www.exdomain.com/create/create.php?t=BATMAN_SLAPPING_ROBBIN.jpg'

~~The field at location contains 'http://www.exdomain.com/create/img/BATMAN_SLAPPING_ROBBIN.jpg'

Comment: What does `var_dump($info['createlink']);` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not requesting the `createlink` field from the table, only `location`. Change your query to this:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT `location`,`createlink` FROM `upload` WHERE `name` = '".$result['name']."'")
```

You should also move away from the deprecated mysql_* functions and switch to PDO/mysqli so that your code will work in future versions of php. This will also allow you to parametrize your queries to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Ohh my goodness :O How did I missed it lol :P That worked perfectly. Thanks a ton mate :)